# How to change ImageView inside viewholder without clicking it or changing all the ImageViews?

Tags: android-studio, onclicklistener, android-viewholder, setimagebitmap

In a specific adapter, i have the simplest ViewHolder:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView image;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_id);

    }
}
```

and the following onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.imagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(MY_BITMAP);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });


}
```

My objective: change the ImageView without clicking on it.However, if if put

```
holder.image.setImageBitmap(MY_BITMAP);
```

outside of onClickListener, it changes all images in my RecyclerView.
How can I achieve this without clicking the image and without changing all the images of my RecyclerView?

PS: my image needs to change after a taking-picture activity gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change specific position you can use 'if statement'(example position 1)

```
if(position == 1){  holder.image.setImageBitmap(MY_BITMAP); }
```

Or if you have list of bitmap, you can populate it by(example named listMyBitmap)

```
holder.image.setImageBitmap(listMyBitmap.get(position));
```

Comment: iin this case, i have only one MY_BITMAP,so the second solution doesn't work for me. So, the first solution, the problem is that i want to put in a if statement only the position i've clicked, not a predetermined position (like position == 1).Do u understand? @Bona Kusuma